# PouchDB authentication with token (Cookie: AuthSession=xyz) lead to unsafe header "Cookie"

Tags: cookies, ionic-framework, header, couchdb, pouchdb

I want to connect to my remote couchdb database by using the access token given by couchdb, this can be done by sending a header with :

```
Cookie: AuthSession={COUCHDB_TOKEN}
```

I have no problem doing this with curl. However with pouchDB with the following code :

```
new PouchDB(url, {
    ajax: { headers: {'Cookie': 'AuthSession=couchdb_token'} }        
});
```

I got the error :

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"
```

Is there a way of putting this token into a header without having this error ?

I have done research but impossible to find a way to use pouchdb synchronization with a remote database without giving username & password, but those should not be stored client side so..

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the browser is blocking the setting of the 'Cookie' request header as this header is directly managed by the browser. You can not set any of [these headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name).

You should authenticate with CouchDB using the _session endpoint. This endpoint will respond with a Set-Cookie header that established the AuthSession cookie in the browser which is sent back to CouchDB in the next calls.

What I usually do is to configure a ProxyAuthentication (Note: this was broken in CouchDB 2.0) mode in CouchDB and then use a custom auth header in my application for authentication. This approach is a bit more complex but will allow you to use your application auth token with CouchDB. 
--- EDIT ---

Please, check if you have the [ProxyAuthentication enabled](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/server/authn.html#proxy-authentication). 
The logic for the auth token is [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/x_auth_token).
You don't required to call to _session endpoint, just build the token with the proper logic.

-- EDIT2 --

Looking into the CouchDB code the Token is generated in this way:

"X-Auth-CouchDB-Token": hex_hmac_sha1(secret, "user@test.org")

Where:

- secret is the key defined by couch_httpd_auth/secret.
- The user is the one provided in the header X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName

You should reproduce this logic in the client side.

Comment: Alright thank you, yes I use the _session endpoint but only with my node server, then I give back the AuthSession cookie to the client but how to use it but by adding it to the header ?

Other option you said is to configure ProxyAuthentication and then use the following  headers : 

X-Auth-CouchDB-Roles: users,blogger
X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName: foo
X-Auth-CouchDB-Token: {SECRET_TOKEN}

The {SECRET_TOKEN} is the same token that we get from asking _session ? Because this is not working for me.

Comment: I found this part of the documentation very unclear, where is this token generated ? : The HTTP header name (X-Auth-CouchDB-Token by default) containing the token used to authenticate the authorization. This token is an HMAC-SHA1 created from the couch_httpd_auth/secret and couch_httpd_auth/x_auth_username. The secret key should be the same on the client and the CouchDB node.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow here is the link where I posted my way of solving it https://stackoverflow.com/a/48356410/7077287