# How to log in to CouchDB without entering username & password

Tags: authentication, couchdb, pouchdb

When I try to log in to my remote CouchDB instance from my script, a popup login appears.

I want my script to log into CouchDB without the user having to enter the password (I'm authenticating users with the Google People API and then authenticating my offline app against a single CouchDB instance).

Instead of using the username and password in my code, CouchDB is demanding a new one each time, via the popup.

```
PouchNotesObj = function (databasename, remoteorigin) {
'use strict';

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'pdb', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'remote', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'formobject', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'notetable', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'searchformobject', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'errordialog', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'dbname', {writable: true});

    var databasename = 'pouchcontacts';

    var remoteorigin = 'https://<remote.path>:6984';
    var hostUrl = 'https://<myapp>.appspot.com/';

    this.dbname = databasename;
    this.pdb = new PouchDB(databasename);
    var remoteDB = new PouchDB(remoteorigin + '/pouchnotes', {skip_setup: true});
    this.remote = remoteDB;

//from https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/issues/121
    var user = {
      cname: 'myusername',
      password: 'mypassword'
    };

    var pouchOpts = {
      skip_setup: true
    };
    var ajaxOpts = {
      ajax: {
        headers: {
            'X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName': 'myusername',
            'X-Auth-CouchDB-Roles': 'user',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(user.cname + ':' + user.password),
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : hostUrl,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With'
        }
      }
    };
    remoteDB.login(user.cname, user.password, ajaxOpts, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        if (err.cname === 'unauthorized' || err.cname === 'forbidden') {
          console.log('Unauthorised user');
        } else {
          //return this.remote.all_docs();
          console.log('Successful login');
        }
      }
    }); 
    this.remote.info()
      .then(console.log.bind(console))
      .catch(console.log.bind(console));

// https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/synching-db/

      this.pdb.replicate.to(this.remote, {
          live: true,
          retry: true
        }).on('change', function (change) {
          console.log('data change (replicate TO): ', change)
        }).on('error', function (err) {
          console.log('sync error (replicate TO): ', err)
        });
      this.pdb.replicate.from(this.remote, {
          live: true,
          retry: true
        }).on('change', function (change) {
          console.log('data change (replicate from): ', change)
        }).on('error', function (err) {
          console.log('sync error (replicate from): ', err)
        });
   };
```

**Update**:

I have now configured my CouchDB instance with all the parameters required for Proxy Authentication.

My script now looks like this:

```
/* Login to CouchDB on remote */
            var pouchOpts = {
              skip_setup: true
            };
            var ajaxOpts = {
              ajax: {
                headers: {
                    'X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName': 'my-user-name',
                    'X-Auth-CouchDB-Roles': 'user',
                    'X-Auth-CouchDB-Token': hex_hmac_sha1('couch_secret', 'Brookes'),
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                    
                  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS',
                  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With'
                }
              }
            };


            var remoteSession = 'https://my-couch-server:6984/_session';
            remoteSession.login(ajaxOpts, function (err, response) {
              if (err) {
                if (err.cname === 'unauthorized' || err.cname === 'forbidden') {
                  console.log('Unauthorised user');
                } else {
                  //return this.remote.all_docs();
                  console.log('Successful login');
                  var remoteDB = new PouchDB('https://my-couch-server:6984/pouchnotes', {skip_setup: true});
                }
              }
            }); 

            /*end couch login*/
```

The error message I am getting is `remoteSession.login is not a function`

If I go to `_session` on my CouchDB host, I get the following:

> {"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":"my-admin-user","roles":["_admin"]},"info":{"authentication_db":"_users","authentication_handlers":["cookie","default"],"authenticated":"default"}}

Comment: In your code remoteSession is a String with the session endpoint url. Is that correct?

Comment: well it ought not to be a string because then it can't be recognised as a URL to be logged into, but it clearly is a string :(

Comment: in the other answer, you said "You should authenticate with CouchDB using the _session endpoint" - how do I do that, please?

Answer (score 2):

CouchDB provides a token based authentication mechanism that may help in your case.

I point you to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202502/7563316) where this mechanism is proposed.

The Proxy Authentication is described [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/server/authn.html#proxy-authentication).

Comment: thanks, that was really helpful. I have changed all the settings on my CouchDB instance as per the Proxy Authentication docs. However, I think I am not pointing the code at the right thing (see update on question)